# Angular - Flag and width issue in ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11 project, I am using ngx-intl-tel-input:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <ngx-intl-tel-input [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mobile_number.errors }" [cssClass]="'form-control mb-3'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" [value]="'+91 0977667755'" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
      [enablePlaceholder]="true" name="mobile_number" formControlName="mobile_number" [phoneValidation]="true" name="mobile_number" formControlName="mobile_number">
    </ngx-intl-tel-input>
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.mobile_number.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.mobile_number.errors.required">Mobile Number is required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I observed two issues:

1. The flags are grayed and not showing real flag.
2. The width is shorter.

[image: flag and width]

angular.json:

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

style.scss:

```
@import '~bs-stepper/dist/css/bs-stepper.min.css';
@import '../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css'
```

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a css issue. Can you confirm if you have linked the css file correctly in your `angular.json` ?

```html
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: It's there. See my updated code. But not working. The width is smaller and can't see the flag

Comment: Can you try putting the css file in the angular.json. If that doesn't fix it we can look at other solutions.

Comment: I did as you advised, but the width is still the same size. See the updated code.  Still smaller

Answer (score 1):

I got flags after

> npm install google-libphonenumber --save

about the width, take a look
https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/issues/234

maybe it can))

Answer (score 0):

try bootstrap version with out css or ngx-bootstrap https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bs-tel-input